# Wrapping usercall from Hex-Rays

Tags: ida, assembly, hexrays

I am trying to call a function generated by Hex-Rays by injecting a DLL, but have so far only managed to crash the process.

This is the code generated by Hex-Rays

```
int __usercall sub_54C3A0@<eax>(int a1@<esi>, void *a2@<ecx>)
{
  char *v2; // eax@1
  char *v3; // edx@1
  char v4; // cl@2
  int result; // eax@4
  char v6[84]; // [sp+0h] [bp-58h]@1

  sub_432BA0(a2);
  dword_81D7CC = 1;
  sub_432B40("xxx_");
  v2 = (char *)sub_431620(55);
  v3 = (char *)(v6 - v2);
  do
  {
    v4 = *v2;
    v2[(_DWORD)v3] = *v2;
    ++v2;
  }
  while ( v4 );
  sub_4330E0(*(_DWORD *)v6);
  sub_437270();
  dword_81D7CC = 0;
  result = 0;
  if ( v6[0] )
  {
    dword_81DAE0 = 0;
    if ( sub_54C480(100, a1) || dword_81DAE0 || sub_54C480(75, a1) || dword_81DAE0 || sub_54C480(50, a1) )
      result = 1;
  }
  return result;
}
```

And this is my code

```
static DWORD hook_address = 0x54C3A0;
__declspec(naked) int hook()
{
    __asm {
        push esi // a1
        push ecx // a2
        call hook_address
        retn 4
    }
}
```

What would the correct wrapper look like, and why?

Comment: It should be `mov esi, a1` , `mov ecx, a2`. Note that `usercall` is not actually any calling convention. It is a way of representing unknown/custom calling conventions. See *[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832139/hooking-usercall-with-inline-asm)* answer.

Comment: I tried that, still get access violation.

Comment: Do it like this: `mov esi, a1`, `mov ecx, a2`, `call hook_address`, `ret`. Using `retn 4` clears 4 bytes from the stack, but usercalls don't need it because their arguments are in registers, not in the stack.

Comment: That worked. Also, the address was wrong all the time. After running the program from IDA the addresses updated. No wonder I got access violations all over the place.

Comment: @AcidShout can you write your comment as an answer so that this question can be marked answered, and also help others in future?

Answer (score 4):

Your hook is wrong because `retn 4` is for `__stdcall`s, not `__usercall`s, and because you must move arguments to registers, not push them. Do it like this:

```
mov esi, a1
mov ecx, a2
call hook_address
ret
```

`retn 4` would clean 4 bytes from the stack, but you didn't push anything, so it's not correct, which is why you use `ret` instead.